# Gollum wiki: include other pages doesn't work

Tags: ruby, github, sinatra, wiki

I'm trying to use the the [Include other pages](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#include-other-pages) syntax in [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) but it doesn't work as I expect to be. 
It doesn't include the content of the another page but it just put a link of it.

For example, in the home page (`http://localhost:4567/Home`) I'm using a syntax like:

```
[[include:testpage]]
```

I expect it includes the content of the page `http://localhost:4567/testpage` (testpage.md) in the home, but it just display a link to `http://localhost:4567/include%3Atestpage`

Can you give me an example of the right syntax?

I'm using Gollum version:

gollum (2.5.0)
gollum-lib (1.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "[include other pages](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#include-other-pages)" in gollum 2.5.1 and everything works as expected, so I guess it was a bug of version 2.5.0

Comment: Were you able to get nested links to work? I can't seem to get [[include:/path/to/page]] to work, but [[include:page]] works.